# Could not convert PHP value of type ... to type .... Expected one of the following types: null, DateTime

Tags: php, symfony

When I supported automatic wiring with Symfony3.4 and moved the command, the following error occurred.
Specifically, add `__construct` and change `$this->getContainer()->get('database_connection');`
to `$this->connection` it changed.
Is there anything wrong with it?

Error

```
[root@localhost Symfony]# php bin/console ahisp:analytics:update-article-pageview

16:46:32 ERROR   [console] Error thrown while running command "ahisp:analytics:update-access-report". 
Message: "Could not convert PHP value of type 'Doctrine\DBAL\Connection' to type 'date'. 
Expected one of the following types: null, DateTime" ["exception" => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ConversionException { …},
"command" => "ahisp:analytics:update-access-report",
"message" => "Could not convert PHP value of type 'Doctrine\DBAL\Connection' to type 'date'. 
Expected one of the following types: null, DateTime"] In ConversionException.php line 88:

Could not convert PHP value of type 'Doctrine\DBAL\Connection' to type 'date'. Expected one of the following types: null, DateTime
```

UpdateAccessReportCommand.php

```php
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;

    protected $connection;

    public function __construct(Connection $connection)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Command execution
     * @param InputInterface $input
     * @param OutputInterface $output
     * @throws Throwable
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $date = new \DateTime($input->getOption('date'));
        $week = $this->getFirstDayOfWeek($date);
        $month = new \DateTime($date->format('Y-m-01'));

        $this->connection->transactional(function () use ($date, $week, $month) {
            // Updated daily access report
            $this->deleteAccessReportDaily($this->connection, $date);
            $this->insertAccessReportDaily($this->connection, $date, 'portal');
            $this->insertAccessReportDaily($this->connection, $date, 'brand');
            $this->insertAccessReportDaily($this->connection, $date, 'shop');
            $this->insertAccessReportDaily($this->connection, $date, 'article');
        });
    }
```

ConversionException.php

```php
    /**
     * Thrown when the PHP value passed to the converter was not of the expected type.
     *
     * @param mixed    $value
     * @param string   $toType
     * @param string[] $possibleTypes
     *
     * @return ConversionException
     */
    public static function conversionFailedInvalidType(
        $value,
        $toType,
        array $possibleTypes,
        ?Throwable $previous = null
    ) {
        $actualType = is_object($value) ? get_class($value) : gettype($value);

        if (is_scalar($value)) {
            return new self(sprintf(
                "Could not convert PHP value '%s' of type '%s' to type '%s'. Expected one of the following types: %s",
                $value,
                $actualType,
                $toType,
                implode(', ', $possibleTypes)
            ), 0, $previous);
        }
        //line 88
        return new self(sprintf(
            "Could not convert PHP value of type '%s' to type '%s'. Expected one of the following types: %s",
            $actualType,
            $toType,
            implode(', ', $possibleTypes)
        ), 0, $previous);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I read the error string, it's telling you that you're passing a Connection Object into parameters of a function which should be A: null (nothing) or B: a DateTime object.

I can't read which line is line 88, but according to your error, this is what is going wrong.

Follow-up question:

is: $this->connection->transactional supposed to have a connection parameter?

Hope this helps you any further!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Sure, I was wondering there, and originally ```function ()``` was in the form of ```function ($connection) ```. ```function($this->connection)``` is a syntax error, and ```function ($connection) ``` gave a similar error.
Is there a way to check if ```transactional``` has a connection parameter? I think it's difficult with ```var_dump```.
Also, I added line 88 just in case.